# Why is my tail still pointing to Something instead of pointing to NULL after I destroy the list

Tags: c, list, linked-list, doubly-linked-list, destroy

so I wrote this code in c that does basic doubly linked list tasks like create the list, insert a node after/before a given current NODE, removes a given current Node and So on, but I ran into this issue when I tried to destroy the list. What's happening is, when I destroy the list, it deallocates all Nodes properly (at least I think so from what I see in the debugger watch), but when I check to see whether the head and tail pointer point to NULL since the Nodes no longer exists, the head points to NULL, but my tail still points to something that I'm not sure whether it is a node from the list that wasn't deallocated properly or something else.

Can someone tell me what's happening? Here is the relevant code;

This is the function that Deallocates all nodes, thus destroying the list

```
void DListDestruct(DList* list) {
DListNode* tempHead = list->head;;

while (tempHead != NULL) {
    tempHead = tempHead->next;
    free(list->head);
    list->head = tempHead;
}

if (list->tail == NULL) {
    list->size = 0;
}


}


    //Creation of the structs for the list    

typedef struct DListNode_struct {
   char *str;
   int blankIndex;
   int blankLength;
   struct DListNode_struct *next;
   struct DListNode_struct *prev;
} DListNode;

typedef struct DList_struct {
   int size;
   DListNode *head;
   DListNode *tail;
} DList;



/* This creates a new list and initializes the head/tail */

void DListConstruct(DList* list) {

    list->head = NULL;
    list->tail = NULL;
    list->size = 0;

}


/* inserts newNode after the given currNode */

void DListInsertAfter(DList* list, DListNode* currNode, DListNode* newNode) {

DListNode* sucNode = NULL;

if (list->head == NULL) {
    list->head = newNode;
    list->tail = newNode;
    list->size = list->size++;
}

else if (currNode == list->tail) {
    list->tail->next = newNode;
    newNode->prev = list->tail;
    list->tail = newNode;
    list->size = list->size++;
}

else {
    sucNode = currNode->next;
    newNode->next = sucNode;
    newNode->prev = currNode;
    currNode->next = newNode;
    sucNode->prev = newNode;
    list->size = list->size++;
}
}


/* inserts newNode before the given currNode */
void DListInsertBefore(DList* list, DListNode* currNode, DListNode* newNode) {
DListNode* predNode;


if (list->head == NULL) {
    list->head = newNode;
    list->tail = newNode;
    list->size = list->size++;
}

else if (currNode->prev != NULL) {
    predNode = currNode->prev;
    newNode->next = currNode;
    newNode->prev = predNode;
    currNode->prev = newNode;
    predNode->next = newNode;
    list->size = list->size++;
}

else if (currNode->prev == NULL) {
    newNode->next = currNode;
    currNode->prev = newNode;
    list->head = newNode;
    list->size = list->size++;
}

}
```

So again, Why is it that when I destroy the List, using the DListDestroy function (the first one on top), all nodes are deallocated, the head pointer points to NULL, but the tail pointer still points to something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `list->size = list->size++;` --> undefined behavior.  Just use `list->size++;`

Comment: Isn't it your job to set tail to NULL? Where are you doing that in `DListDestruct()`? Instead of `if (list->tail == NULL) {
    list->size = 0;
}` what you need is `list->tail = NULL;
    list->size = 0;`.

Comment: I just a beginner in C, so I thought that after I free all nodes the correct way, both the head and tail pointer should point to NULL since the nodes were already freed. Isn't that what the head and tail pointer supposed to point to by the time I free all nodes?

Comment: Which line of code do you think makes `tail` NULL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the tail stil points to the address of the node you freed, so now it points to some garbage.

The head points to wherever "tempHead" points and by the end of the loop it points to null, because during the insertion process, you put null in the next of the last node.

In conclusion, the tail points to the address of the last node, which is garbage.
The head points to the last node's next which is NULL.

Comment: okay it makes sense what you said. But I need my tail to point to NULL after I free all nodes and not to the address of the node I freed. So is there a way I can destroy the list and have my tail point to NULL by the time all nodes are freed?

Comment: add this line after you finish freeing all nodes `list->tail = NULL;`

Comment: @einacio tail will hold NULL if you set it to NULL, otherwise it won't. Simple as that.

Comment: Okay thanks guys. Your answers did clarify what I was thinking about. I was pushing on myself trying to find a different way to destroy the list because I thought that was the issue when I could just set the tail to NULL. Thanks again